# Angular2: subscribe to BehaviorSubject not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject, behaviorsubject

I have an `Alert.Service.ts` which saves alerts fetched from another service in an array. In another `header.component.ts`, I want to get the real-time size of that array.

So, in `Alert.Service.ts` I have

```
@Injectable()
export class AlertService {

public static alerts: any = [];

// Observable alertItem source
private alertItemSource = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
// Observable alertItem stream
public alertItem$ = this.alertItemSource.asObservable();

constructor(private monitorService: MonitorService) {
    if (MonitorService.alertAgg != undefined) {
        AlertService.alerts = MonitorService.alertAgg['alert_list'];
        AlertService.alerts.push({"id":111111,"severity":200}); //add a sample alert

        this.updateAlertListSize(AlertService.alerts.length);

        MonitorService.alertSource.subscribe((result) => {
            this.updateAlertList(result);
        });
    }
}

private updateAlertList(result) {
    AlertService.alerts = result['alert_list'];
    this.updateAlertListSize(AlertService.alerts.length);
}


// service command
updateAlertListSize(number) {
  this.alertItemSource.next(number);
}
```

And, in `header.component.ts`, I have

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-header',
providers: [ AlertService  ],
templateUrl: 'app/layout/header.component.html',
styles: [ require('./header.component.scss')],
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
private subscription:Subscription;
private alertListSize: number;

constructor(private alertSerivce: AlertService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.alertSerivce.alertItem$.subscribe(
        alertListSize => {this.alertListSize = alertListSize;});
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component is destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

I expect the `alertListSize` gets updated as long as the `alerts` array in `Alert.Service.ts` changed. However, it's always `0` which is the initial value when the `BehaviorSubject` is created. It seems that the subscribe part doesn't work.

Comment: If you tried and subscribe directly on `alertItemSource` (and putting it public) is the value correctly returned?

Comment: @PRacicot I've tried that, the value is not updated either.

Comment: By looking at your code, I see that you `AlertService` constructor has a parameter.  But in your `header.component.ts` constructor you have the basic DI.  In my current ng2 projects, all my Injectable services have empty constructor.  I'd suggest trying to mock a fake `MonitorService` and have an empty constructor see if the BehaviorSubject actually runs and returns the correct value.

Comment: @PRacicot Sorry for the confusing `MonitorService`. It's actually injected in the parent level `app.component.ts`. So, it's accessible inside `Monitor.Service.ts`. After commenting out all `MonitorService` in `AlertService`, the value gets updated. Since `AlertService` depends on the slow `MonitorSerivce`, the `if (MonitorService.alertAgg != undefined)` is false when `AlertService is constructed.

Comment: @PRacicot Is there a way to force the `AlertService` gets constructed after the `MonitorService` fully prepared?

Comment: Add a `MonitorService` DI in your `header.component`.  Then manually call the constructor of your `AlertService`.  Another approach would be @BingLu to have an empty constructor for `AlertService`. Then in the constructor of your `header.component` have both `MonitorService` and `AlertService` injected.  Finally in the `ngOnInit() {}` call a new method created in your `AlertService` which will contain your current `MonitorService` constructors logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116567/discussion-between-pracicot-and-bing-lu).

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely using the 'providers: [ AlertService  ] ' statement in multiple places, and you have two instances of your service.   You should only provide your services at the root component, or some common parent component if you want a singleton service.   Providers are hierarchical , and providing it at a parent component will make the same instance available to all children.